# insertHTML to insert Div in contentEditable div does not make it draggable or resizeable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, execcommand

The crux of the issue is that I have a contentEditable div. I execute the following JS:

```
     document.execCommand('enableAbsolutePositionEditor', false, null);
     document.execCommand('enableObjectResizing', false, null);
     document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, "<div class='inner1' style='position:absolute;left:100px;right:100px;'>innerDiv</div>");
```

Goal is to enable entry of some div inside and make it moveable and resizeable. This is the basic to start. I would then like to make that div itself contentEditable, if possible so that blocks of text can be moved around or resized (using the first two commands). I also want to do so in such a way that the contentEditable's undo/redo button has control over it.

The div gets inserted but it is neither draggable nor  resizeable. There are other issues (edit inside overwrites and does not move existing content) but I need to get around the basic two objectives first. Do I need to install some jQuery plugin for this?

Comment: Like a textarea right ? http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/AbKTQ/

Comment: Yes like textarea but textarea is not contenteditable (has its own issues) so a div must be used.  In your jsfiddle I do not see the ability to add a div inside the contenteditable div and then resize or move it.

Comment: Ok I totally don't have the skills to help you but with some search I found this http://jsfiddle.net/q6q05f1b/. let me know if it help.